# Read json data from azure website

Tags: android, json, azure, android-studio

I try to read data from azure website for my android application. But when i try to reach it gives me an error.

But when i look with [this website](http://jsonformat.com/) i can see json data.

I can see all json data so truely. But somehow when i enter the url my browser i can't see the data. And my url is http://tcm-test-api.azurewebsites.net/api/movie/search?term=%22Batman%22&page=1

Comment: Try turning off Custom errors in you web config file and retry. You should at least get a detailed error message. Look at this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020103/webapis-messagean-error-has-occurred-on-iis7-not-in-iis-express

Comment: @MuchOverflow i understood problem but i couldn't understant how can i change it because i try to read json data from this website. But i get nullPointerException but i can read json datas from other websites.

Comment: When you try the connection to this api, try setting the content-type as `application/json; charset=utf-8` It would be better if you can show how are you connecting to this service from android

Comment: @MuchOverflow i try to connect like this and sorry for delaying http://paste.ubuntu.com/15340900/

Comment: Check this stackoverflow question for how to set the content type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263854/java-httpclient-changing-content-type

Comment: @MuchOverflow but they're using a different structure i couldn't figure out unfortunately :(

Comment: @MuchOverflow i fixed it but now i'm getting this error: The requested resource does not support http method 'POST' and i searched in stackoverflow and google but i couldn't find for android application. Could you help me?

Comment: this is a GET request so you should call it with `HttpGet` object.

Comment: @MuchOverflow thanks for help you saved my time

Comment: Good to know everything worked out for you :)

Comment: @MuchOverflow Please post a proper answer summarizing the fix. Currently all the details are buried in comments, and there's no answer posted (so, no ability to properly accept an answer).

Comment: @DavidMakogon I posted the answer as per your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting **Content-Type** to `application/json;charset=utf-8` in your Http request header.  In android when you create the HttpUrlConnection do it as follows

```
URL myURL = new URL(serviceURL);
HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)myURL.openConnection();
myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
```